# iOS10 rounded UIButton show on StoryBoard

Tags: ios, uibutton, storyboard

I am trying to create a rounded corner UIButton.

Something like this `layer.cornerRadius = 30` in my custom button class and also updated it in my storyBoard

[image: click here for storyboard image.]

I am able to get my rounded corner UIButton. When I run it on simulator it works fine.

[image: Button on simulator looks like this.]

However, on my storyboards it still looks like a square button. How can I update my storyboard to get round button?

Comment: The only way to get Interface Builder to render custom views is using the `IBDesignable`/`IBInspectable` directives. You could add these to your `CircleButton`. I can’t go into detail right now. Search for `IBDesignable UIButton`.

Comment: @Arthur thanks it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found the the answer. Thanks to devslopes.com

First add @IBDesignable in your custom class and then add the following code.

```
@IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 30
{
    didSet{
       layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
    }
}
override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
{
    layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
}
```

After adding this function in your custom class. Just update the value of corner radius in your storyboard for that button and you can see the circular button on your storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

your button will looks square in storyboard definitely because `layer.cornerRadius = 30` executes at run time. same like if you write for loop in editor then it is not giving result at there but it works when you run it like wise it will not show rounded on story board!!

Comment: is there any way I can show rounded corner button on my storyBoard?

Comment: according to my knowledge no!!